# How to get field as result of LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Can LINQ to some like this:

```
 var results = Table.Where(row => row.result != null).ToArray();
```

And it returns collection of Table- for example: result[0].result==100500;

But,
I need an IEnumerable results ,where results== row№1.result and row№2.result ... and so on.

For example, results[0]=100500;results[1]=2000; and so on.

Comment: you probably want linq select operator https://www.udemy.com/blog/linq-select/

Comment: Yes,it is:) May be this code are right?  var results = Table.Where(row => row.result != null).Select(row => row.result);

Comment: You can select a new anonymous object from the enumerated type as well.

var results = Table.Where(row => row.Result != null).Select(p => new { p.SomeField, p.SomeOtherField});

foreach(var result in results)
{
  Console.WriteLine(result.SomeField + " " + result.SomeOtherField);
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do:

```
var results = Table.Where(row => row.result != null)
                   .Select(row => row.result)
                   .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var list = (from t in Table
            where t.result != null
            select t);
```